# How to store URL of clicked hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring, jquery-events

I am displaying a warning dialog box whenever user tries to navigate from current page without saving data on current page. Its working fine now I want to call a function (Spring controller, its kind of java function which handled URL mappings ) when user clicks on <kbd>Ok</kbd> (in warning dialog box) and then he should get redirectd to desired page.
Let me try to make it simple (Its confusing for me also):

1. User is on registration page, he/she  made some changes and didn't save it.
2. Now user clicked on any other link for example he clicked on `About Us` link.
3. Now I want to execute my spring controller.
4. After execution of controller user should get navigated to `About Us` page.
   For this I need to save value of clicked hyperlink and pass it to my spring controller.
   So how can I store URL of clicked link (URL of `About Us`  page in above example) ?

PS: I will really appreciate if anybody can edit my question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: you can simply get the url of clicked anchor element using javascript or jquery, then pass it to your controller, get it in your controller from request or session..save it some where..what's the problem in this case?

Comment: @Vivek: Thanks, its really easy and workable solution. The problem it didn't come out of my mind as I am newbie. :)

Comment: @Vivek: Thanks for the edit but I want to store URL of clicked link not of the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use jQuery, you can attach an event handler to onclick to all links in the page and once clicked the handler should save the href attribute to some variable. then create a onbeforeunload event listener on your window, where you can use the value however you want, call your controller or save the value in a cookie or something.

Comment: That's sounds good. I am calling my controller in `window.onunload`. What if user do a page refresh ? because even in page refresh warning dialog is displayed.

Comment: well if you do a refresh, then the variable will hold no url so a link was not clicked and you do nothing

Comment: It will give error in controller as I am passing no value. Do we have any workaround ?

Comment: can't you skip the controller call if there is no value ? or if no value then serve it document.location.href or #

Comment: Ya that will serve the purpose. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Are all the links on the page pointing to your spring application? If there are no external links anywhere (pointing to external resource) - then you could write a simple [Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) where you can save the requested page into the session.

Otherwise, if there are links to external resources - you would need to rewrite them  from `www.external.com` to `www.my.com\MagicController?requestedPage=www.external.com`. Controller will save the link and send a redirect in HTTP header to the requested page. This is a common practice - even google does that (check out the google search result links for how it will look like).

**Added:** Weird, but google does that only on some rare occasions, so you probably won't be able to find an example there.

Comment: Ya I have some external link also.

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, you should run some Javascript **or** server side code to replace all of the external links to `www.my.com\MagicController?requestedPage=www.external.com`. As for the local pages - I'd use Filter, as Filters work much faster than the full roundtrip through additional controller.

Answer (score 0):

Don't require to preserve the href of selected tab.Do one thing attach same javascript function with each tab and pass the "this" as parameter of function.

Function of the javascript is

```
function Attach(ele)  
{

// 1. Find the handle of selected tag and store in the variable. 
   ele=$(ele);

// 2. Find the value of href
   var href=ele.attr("href");

// 3. Perform server side operation you want.

// 4. redirect to another page.
   window.location=href;

  return false;

}
```